# Excel stacked bar chart not stacking correctly

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a stacked bar chart which isn't stacking correctly. The bars are overlapping each other, rather than the start of one segment, rendering at the end of the previous segment... Any ideas?

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you sent the chart to others, would this issue be reproduced? Maybe you need to check whether you choose the Secondary Axis for one data series.

Comment: seems you have multiple data series. Can you post some sample data?

Comment: try to follow the [tutorial[(https://exceljet.net/chart-type/stacked-bar-chart) and have the data arranged as per needed. Sometimes excel chart can't draw properly with (same data &) different arrangement.